# Hashicorp Vault: Readonly policy not working

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am exploring Hashicorp Vault, and I am trying to create a read-only policy. This policy should only allow users to read key(s).

Below is the policy definition:

```
path "transit/*" {
  capabilities = ["read", "list"]
}
```

I am trying to read key under secrets/transit (API Call: http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/transit/keys/key1)

I am using the below CLI command to get the key (key1 in this case):

```
bash-5.1# vault read transit/keys/key1
```

However I get the below error:

```
Error reading transit/keys/key1: Error making API request.

URL: GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/transit/keys/key1
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
        * permission denied
```

The same command works with the master token, So I guess there is nothing wrong with the command itself, but the problem is with the policy.

Interestingly, if I grant more access to the policy as below, then I can access the keys which is really confusing. I don't want to grant users create/update/delete access.

```
path "transit/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "update", "read", "delete", "list"]
}
```

Can someone point me where I am mistaken? Thanks.

Comment: How are you authorised when you try?  Have you attached the policy to a token, or auth method? https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/getting-started-policies?in=vault/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I changed the policy name and the same policy definition mentioned above started working as expected. I'm still not sure why or what was wrong with old policy name.